# Vuforia Image Target Virtual Button not responding

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, virtual, vuforia

The Virtual Button on my Image Target does not respond at all to presses on physical card.

I have tried following a tutorial on how to implement a virtual button, tried different image targets with different point features and making sure vuforia is updated. The image target has enough of point features:
[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjMoD.jpg) . It seems like no matter where I place the virtual button, and no matter the size it will not recognize as being pressed. The sensitivity has also been tested on all levels.

Following is all the relevant code in the script attached to the image target. The GameObject btnObj is the virtual button which is a child of the image target:

```
public class vButton : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
{

    public GameObject btnObj;

    void Start()
    {
        btnObj.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterEventHandler(this);
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button pressed!");
    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button released!");
    }
}
```

You would expect that when the button is pressed the Debug.Log would get triggered, but it does not. Nothing at all happens.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
```

For this:

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualAbstractButtonBehaviour vb)
```

And do the same for the other method, regards!